# Numpy Trapezoidal Rule

Tags: numpy

Can anyone explain how numpy's trapezoidal rule works.

```
x = [[0,1,2], [1,2,3]]
y = [[0,1,2], [1,1,2], [1,1,2]]
np.trapz(y, x, axis = 0)
```

Gives:

```
array([1.5, 2. , 4. ])
```

when the rows are not equal.

I can understand why this might work:

```
x = [0,1,2]
np.trapz(y, x, axis = 0)
```

But I don't understand why this does either:

```
x = [0, 1]
np.trapz(y, x, axis = 0)
```

Comment: The doc page looks fairly detailed, and the [source] link appears to be pure python, so you/we can see all details.  I'd suggest explaining more what is puzzling.

Comment: `x` is used in the code to actually create `d`. As long as the computed `d` has a shape broadcastable to `y`, the computing formula will work. More specifically, if `x` is 1D and has only two values, it will make `d` broadcastable with any non-null `y` shape.